# design for not returning everything in `GET /posts`

Tags: rest, http, restful-url

I'm making a personal blog with `API + SPA`.

API should be `RESTful` and SPA is `angular`.

For admin's panel posts table or landing page (with api `GET /posts`), I don't want to include post content, It just increase size of data transfer. also `GET /posts` response needs id in each item but other APIs don't need them because it is in URL (`POST /posts/{{id}}`, `PUT /posts/{{id}}`, `GET /posts/{{id}}`)

What is correct design for it?

Comment: There's a LOT of micro-decisions that go into the 'design' of an API, and there is no one correct design. You should try to write some more specific questions about things you're uncertain about. Don't ask stack overflow to write a technical spec.

Comment: More specific than this? " there is a post entity/resource - it has a content field than contain a lot of data - table don't need that data. so if excluded save a lot of bandwidth and time - in rest all endpoint of a resource has same scheme - what should I do? "

Comment: If your question is: Is my collection endpoint allowed to have *less* data for it's individual items than if I did a GET request directly on those items, then the answer generally is: 'yes, many APIs do this'. Is it good? I think it's subjective and a bit hard to say. Depends on the format of your API too.